# Django : object.filter().value_list() problem

Tags: python, django

I am trying to render data related to a model attribute which is inputed in the frontend by the user in a django view. Unfortunately, I keep running in the same problem
here is my view:

```
@method_decorator(login_required, name='dispatch')
class SupplierPage(LoginRequiredMixin,APIView):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        query = request.GET.get('search_ress', None)
        context = {}

        #if query and request.method == 'GET':
        Supplier = supplier.objects.filter(supplier = query)
        
        
        labels = Item.objects.filter(fournisseur = query).values_list('reference', flat=True)[:10]
        print(labels)
        default_items = Item.objects.filter(fournisseur = query).values_list('number_of_sales', flat=True)[:10]
        print(default_items)
        
        label1s = Item.objects.filter(fournisseur = query).values_list('reference', flat=True)[:10]
        default_item1s = Item.objects.filter(fournisseur = query).values_list('number_of_orders_placed', flat=True)[:10]
        
            
        context.update({'Supplier' : Supplier, 'labels':labels, 'default_items':default_items,'label1s':label1s, 'default_item1s':default_item1s})


        return render(request, 'Supplier.html',context)
```

now in my log, I get this:

```
DEBUG (0.001) SELECT "dashboard_item"."reference", "dashboard_item"."fournisseur", "dashboard_item"."demand_30_jours", "dashboard_item"."stock_reel", "dashboard_item"."en_cours_de_reception", "dashboard_$
DEBUG (0.001) SET search_path = 'pierre','public'; args=None
DEBUG (0.001) SELECT "dashboard_item"."reference" FROM "dashboard_item" WHERE "dashboard_item"."fournisseur" IS NULL LIMIT 10; args=()
DEBUG (0.001) SET search_path = 'pierre','public'; args=None
DEBUG (0.001) SELECT "dashboard_item"."number_of_sales" FROM "dashboard_item" WHERE "dashboard_item"."fournisseur" IS NULL LIMIT 10; args=()
DEBUG (0.001) SET search_path = 'pierre','public'; args=None
DEBUG (0.001) SELECT "dashboard_item"."reference" FROM "dashboard_item" WHERE "dashboard_item"."fournisseur" IS NULL LIMIT 10; args=()
DEBUG (0.001) SET search_path = 'pierre','public'; args=None
DEBUG (0.001) SELECT "dashboard_item"."number_of_orders_placed" FROM "dashboard_item" WHERE "dashboard_item"."fournisseur" IS NULL LIMIT 10; args=()
```

and here is the log in gunicorn:

```
start 2020-08-24 22:48:40.511910
BOLSEIRA
<QuerySet ['372600', '372750', '372650', '372700', '372150', '289807', '289922', '289840', '289923', '372310', '372500']>
<QuerySet [62.0, 58.0, 74.0, 60.0, 16.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 2.0, 36.0]>
start 2020-08-24 22:48:41.782654
None
<QuerySet []>
<QuerySet []>
```

it is weird because the log seems to say that nothing is rendered because the query does not match anything, which does not make sense as I verified that the database contains the proper columns and they are all populated. In addition, the data for `Supplier` and `Supplier_item` gets rendered properly. Actually I am not sure I understand the `IS NULL` in the log.

I am a bit confused about what is going on and after too many hours I cannot find a solution to it. Is there anything that I am not seeing here?

Comment: what exactly you don't understand, query = request.GET.get('search_ress', None)

Comment: this is what contains the user input in the template. What don't get is why the log says ```WHERE "dashboard_item"."fournisseur" IS NULL``` while ```Supplier = supplier.objects.filter(supplier = query)``` works just fine right above. There must be something off in my query but I am not able to figure out what

Comment: How do you know "while Supplier = supplier.objects.filter(supplier = query) works just fine right above" ? The debug log cuts short.
Can you just debug this and see what value you are getting in "query" ?
Also just to be clear, generally python classes start with a capital letter while variables start with small, so just verify if "Supplier = supplier.objects.filter(supplier = query)" is correct. I think it should be "supplier = Supplier.objects.filter(supplier = query)"

Comment: I say it works fine because the proper data is rendered in the frontend

Comment: Are you sure that the search field in your HTML is actually named `search_ress`?  Print out `request.GET`, to see exactly what the field names being submitted are.

Comment: i just updated my question to show more log. Yes that's the name, not great but I am a beginner ^^